# Select mesh perimeter

Tags: python

I would like to select in python the visible perimeter of a mesh. My idea is to get only the external vertices, not all visible.

Any idea or link that can help me?

Answer (score 7):

**`BMEdge.is_boundary`**

---

Can select boundary edges using `BMEdge.is_boundary` Below is a test script, run in edit mode

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context

obj = context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.select_mode |= {'EDGE'}
for e in bm.edges:
    e.select = e.is_boundary
bm.select_flush_mode()   
me.update()
```

Not sure here if you are after the "silhouette" verts. [As in your question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48221/anyone-know-how-detect-what-vertex-are-in-the-edges-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh is not very complex, you can do this manually.

1. Switch to Edit Vertex mode.
2. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>LMB</kbd> and move the mouse. You will notice the dynamic selection region appears.
3. Try drawing a circular selection region with some radius. Don't release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>LMB</kbd>.
4. Once the circle is complete, don not release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>LMB</kbd>, pick a larger radius and do that again. You will see that the inner circle is now inverted and your selection region looks like a donut. Vertices inside that area are selected.

Second way is to enable the [`LoopTools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html) add-on in User Preferences (search for it as LoopTools - without space). This extension brings new menu items in the 3d-view.

Select a few consequent vertices that belong to the perimeter and then try Select / Edge Loops. This may or may not work, depends on your mesh. Works well on spheres.

Comment: The mesh can be very complex and I want to do all with python. More or less, I want the same you get when select an object in the viewport and you see a highlight color in the perimeter, including internal holes.