# Anyone know how detect what vertex are in the edges of a mesh?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, geometry

Anyone know how detect what vertex are in the edges of a mesh?

I want math code, not a user interface procedure.

Really, I want the same function that Blender has when you select an object and you can see a small "focus" color around all the silhouette of the mesh.

Any idea, or advice (including where is defined the focus in C code) will be welcome.

Comment: It is unclear to me what *vertex in edges* means. The selection code should be in 
[EDBM_select_pick](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/source/blender/editors/mesh/editmesh_select.c#l1815), [view3d.select Operator](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_select.c#l2326)

Comment: Do you want the projected 2d silhouette?   http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?283721-Mesh-Silhouette-My-first-Bmesh-Operator&p=2529842&viewfull=1#post2529842  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014293/2d-outline-algorithm-for-projected-3d-mesh

Comment: @batFINGER Yes, I want  project a silhoutte..I'm going to look at you suggestion.

Comment: Freestyle has a silhouette option for outlining, in [source/blender/freestyle/intern/view_map](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/freestyle/intern/view_map/) you will find Silhouette.cpp and SilhouetteGeomEngine.cpp which might help. I expect [draw_mesh_object_outline() in drawobject.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/drawobject.c$3919) would be the place that draws the outline but you will need to trace it back to find how it generates the derived mesh sent to it.

Answer (score -4):

[image]

- The Blender Compositor can

  - Identify, Blur or Dilate, a Pixel Selection to produce a silhouette.
  - The Pixel Selection can be a Rendered Object
- Freestyle can outline objects as well

The above was done with Freestyle