# is_manifold only selecting disconnected verts and not bordering vertices

Tags: python, bmesh

The .is_manifold operator below is only taking completely disconnected verts and not the bordering open area with disconnected verts. There doesn't seam to be an is_border function. Any suggestions?

import bpy
import bmesh

```
mesh = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh) 

for v in bm.verts:
    if len(v.link_edges) not in (4,4) and v.is_manifold:
        v.select_set(True)
```

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47192/select-mesh-perimeter

Answer (score 0):

The solution is "is_boundary" but this is inconsistent with the select all by trait<non manifold in the select menu.